# Dataproc Jupyter initialisation issue bind address in use

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I was able to deploy a cluster on dataproc and include the jupyter.sh initialisation script but after opening a ssh terminal to my master node and running the command (while substituting my values)

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=<cluster-zone> \
  --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" "<cluster-name>-m"
```

I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch instance:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

I read online I could use `gcloud auth login` to authentication my account to the vm so I completed that and was prompted to enter a passphrase as part of generating public/private rsa key pair

When I did all that I got the error `bind: Address already in use` and when I try to connect Chrome to the port 8123 it reports "There is no internet connection"

Answer (score 0):

Seems that running the command to ssh onto vm using a Google Cloud SDK shell worked better than the web based ssh prompt